# Could not convert socket to TLS on Apache Commons Mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, apache-commons, apache-commons-email

I have a problem connecting to a SMTP Server with Apache Commons Mail. I have tried everything but the only thing I can find online is for Java Mail.
This is my error:

> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
>     nested exception is:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have seen that you can fix the issue on Java Mail with `props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");` for example, but I can't a equivalent command to use on Apache Commons.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really connecting to Gmail, you shouldn't need that.  The Gmail certificate will be trusted by the default trust store.  If you've configured a non-default trust store, add the Gmail certificate to that trust store using the [InstallCert](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert) program.